# Simple method to remove pattern matching regex from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a more succinct way than `@string.gsub(/regex/, '')` to cut a pattern from a string?

I know `#slice` exists, but I need a reverse of it, returning the portions that were not sliced.

```
"one\ntwo\three".gsub(/\n/, '')
#=> "onetwothree"
```

Maybe it is just me, but my code is littered with these `gsub(/regex/, '')` bits. I wish there was something like

```
"one\ntwo\three".trim(/\n/)
```

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: You could remove the space after the comma.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That would return an enumerator, which is not what the OP wants. Actually, there has been someone who tried to change the feature: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10927, which I think will be rejected.

Comment: This is a bad question, it's completely opinion based. For example, I think `slice!` is more succinct than `gusb`, but @CarySwoveland does not. If you really want to write `trim` instead of `gsub` then just define a local method in your ruby file or one of your initializers.

Comment: If you're losing sleep, you could write a method `String#gsub_remove`.

Comment: @sawa, I meant just the space, being facetious. It was late... (Ha! You're thinking: "You call that late?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is the simplest you can do.